# Python: Why does this generator not continue from yield?

Tags: python, while-loop, generator

I was trying to make a prime number generator in python but I ran into a problem. Here is my code

```
def prime_generator():
    n = 2
    while n < 100:
        for i in range(2, n):
            if n % i == 0:
                break
        else:
            yield n

        n += 1
```

I thought that this should generate the prime numbers less than 100. It consists of a while loop that takes *n*, starting at 2, and uses a for loop to decide if it is prime or not. If *n* is not prime it increments *n* by 1 and continues the loop until it yields a prime n.

However, whenever I run `print(next(prime_generator()))` multiple times, I just get a bunch of 2s as an output.  Stepping it though the debugger, I noticed that every time python would run `next(prime_generator())` it would restart the generator and reset *n = 2*  instead of leaving off from `yield n` which should then increment *n* and continue the while loop.  Why does it restart? Shouldn't it continue from yield because it is a generator?

Comment: Your `else` doesn't seem to have the right level of indentation.

Comment: Btw, else is a allowed keyword after for LOOP. That's why you' get no error.

Comment: @John I think the OP meant to do that. It's a for/else construct. I tested it, and the code works as-is, but not if you "fix" it.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Good point. Given the rarity of `for ... else` compared to `if ... else` it seemed like a good guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reuse the generator instead of creating a new one each time.

```
primes = prime_generator()
print(next(primes))
print(next(primes))
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `prime_generator()` creates the generator so you would be creating a generator every time. Instead, do this:

```
pg = prime_generator()
print(next(pg))
print(next(pg))
print(next(pg))
```

Then you would get what you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

calling `print(next(prime_generator()))` everytime which result in printing 2 each time means  each time you run this, you are creating a new generator object which is equivalent to

`obj1 = prime_generator(), obj2=prime_generator()`
... so on

so each time a new object is created and you are printing that new object, that is why you are getting the 2 as output each time.

to solve the issue, call generator object once as `object = prime_generator()`
and then keep doing `print(next(object))` till you reach at last prime number, to get all the prime numbers in one single go you can use `all_prime = list(object)`.